# How to use a custom type u64 of "typedef unsigned long long u64;" in a header file without actually including another header file

Tags: typedef, declaration, forward

How to use a custom type u64 of "typedef unsigned long long  u64;" in a header file without actually including another header file? I have seen Q&A for typedef struct and all using forward declaration, but what when it comes to something like the below snippet:

```
          //my_type.h
          typedef          int        s32;
          typedef unsigned long long  u64;
          typedef          long long  s64;


          //my_foo.h
          s32 foo(s32 value1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the typedef into your own header/source file.

Comment: that doesnt help, actually
it still says "unknow type"

Comment: @Mahi: post a short, self contained example that demonstrates your issue.